# Ubuntu 19.10 fractional scaling cursor issues

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-resolution, cursor, 19.10, scaling

I've currently got Ubuntu 19.10 installed on my laptop, this laptop has a 4K screen and as my secondary monitor, I'm using an FHD (1080p) screen

I've tried both X11:

`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['x11-randr-fractional-scaling']"`

and Wayland:

`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"`

to see if the cursor issues would disappear but my mouse keeps flickering and sometimes it disappears completely, I'm not sure if there are any fixes regarding this at all as my secondary screen is impossible to use with the scaling off.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can use **xrandr** there is a hacky way to fix this:

```
xrandr --output <external-monitor> --scale 0.9999x0.9999
```

Example:

```
xrandr --output eDP-1 --scale 0.9999x0.9999
```

This fixed a similar issue I had with flickering cursor.